# Proof that $\int\delta(t)\cos(t)dt = 1$ using integration by parts

Tags: integration, dirac-delta

According to the properties of the Dirac Delta function $\int\delta(t)\cos(t)dt = \cos(0) = 1$.

I tried proving this using integration by parts but got stumped:

$
\require{cancel}
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\delta(t)\cos(t)dt = H(t)\cos(t)\big|_{-\infty}^{\infty} + \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}H(t)\sin(t)dt = \cancel{0 \cdot \cos(t)|_{-\infty}^{0}} + 1 \cdot \cos(t)\big|_{0}^{\infty} + \cancel{ \int_{-\infty}^{0}0 \cdot \sin(t)dt } + \int_{0}^{\infty}1 \cdot \sin(t)dt = \cos(t)\big|_0^{\infty} - \cos(t)|_0^{\infty} = 0
$

$H$ is the step function.

Comment: What makes you think that such an integration by parts is valid?

Comment: Note, when you see $\cos(t)\vert_0^\infty$ you are in trouble.  It diverges by oscillation.  Therefore, this calculation is invalid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The integral of $H(t) \sin(t)$ over an infinite domain is obviously not convergent; it oscillates between $-1$ and $1$ as the upper limit grows.

Instead, you need to e.g. choose some $a>0$ and compute
$$
\begin{align}
\int_{-a}^a \delta(t) \cos(t) \ {\rm d}t
&= \left[H(t) \cos(t) \right]_{-a}^a + \int_{-a}^a H(t) \sin(t) \ {\rm d}t
\\ &= \cos(a) + \int_0^a \sin(t) \ {\rm d}t
\\ &= \cos(a) - \left[\cos(a) - \cos(0)\right]
\\ &= 1
\end{align} 
$$
Now you can take the limit $a \to \infty$ safely. (The oscillating $\cos(a)$ terms have cancelled.)

---

*Edit:* In some sense your calculation would still have "given you the right answer" if you had been slightly more careful with your evaluation of $\left[H(t) \cos(t) \right]_{-\infty}^\infty$. For some reason you split it up into $[0,\infty)$ and $(-\infty,0)$ and then in one of these you chose $H(0)=0$ and $H(0)=1$. This isn't at all consistent! The more consistent thing would be to directly evaluate $H(\infty) = 1$ and $H(-\infty) = 0$ and write "$\cos(\infty)$"... but obviously this now makes clear why you should be careful with $\infty$s! Had you ploughed ahead and written $\cos(\infty) - \left[\cos(t) \right]_0^\infty = \cos(0) = 1$ you would have at least got the right answer however. Then you might realize that you should go back and replace $\infty \to a$ throughout to be more precise.